# Не удаётся опубликовать проект на .NET MAUI если использовать собственный генератор кода

Tags: .net, maui, кодогенераторы

Я написал собственный генератор кода, который прекрасно работает в сборках Debug/Release, но по какой-то причине он вызывает ошибку при публикации проекта для Windows:

```
файл ресурсов "E:\VisualStudio\Generator\Generator\obj\project.assets.json" не содержит целевого объекта для "netstandard2.0". Проверьте, что восстановление выполнено и вы включили "netstandard2.0" в TargetFrameworks своего проекта.
```

Вот только генератор кода включает `netstandard2.0` в `TargetFrameworks`, так что я без понятия, что мне надо сделать.
 А если просто запустить отладку в режиме Debug/Release, то подобной проблемы нет.
Так же я заметил, что если вызвать `dotnet restore` в проекте генератора кода, то файл `project.assets.json` будет правильным, но почему-то при публикации проекта MAUI он берёт и переписывает его на неправильный, так ещё и жалуется после этого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял, что-то не так с процессом публикации, если делать это через графический интерфейс VisualStudio, то есть, вот так: `Сборка -> Опубликовать выбранные элементы`.
Однако, если открыть терминал и ввести туда команду для публикации, то всё будет работать так, как должно, и никаких странных ошибок не будет:

```
dotnet publish -f net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0 -c Release -p:RuntimeIdentifierOverride=win10-x86
```